# SQL login mapping when attaching databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, authentication

A typical scenario: I have a SQL Server 2008 or 2012 with many SQL Server logins and databases, and I must transfer some of my databases to another SQL Server.

The questions is: what is the best way to deal with the corresponding SQL Server logins?

Say, I have a SQL Server login defined on the SQL Server level, named MyUser, which has certain rights, such as `db_datareader` in my SQL Server database `ABC` via user mapping.

What I am currently doing is as follows:

1. Back up the `ABC` database
2. Restore the database to another SQL server. The database has `MyUser` login in its security settings, but there is no such SQL Server login at the SQL Server level yet
3. Now I need to create the same `MyUser` login on the SQL Server level and map it to the existing database login. When I do that, I get an error "User, group, or role 'MyUser' already exists in the current database."

It seems the only way to deal with this is to delete the existing user from the database, then create it at the SQL Server level and then map it to the database, which would create a new login at the database level. Seems like a lot of tedious work, especially if the old database login had a lot of settings associated with it which will now have to be recreated.

Is there a better/simple way of dealing with this chore?

Comment: You need to be more **precise** with your vocabulary: on the **server-level**, you have a **Login** which is not going to be part of the database backup - since it's at the server level. Such a *login* can then have a **user** in any of the databases you have - and those **users** are part of the database and thus will be backed up and restored. You need to be clear to keep **login** (server-level) and **user** (database-level) clearly apart